Spring @Configuration Bean not excluded using excludeFilters when running tests
I have a main class that uses @ComponentScan along with excludeFilters to exclude a class that is used from a library.
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example"},
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                        org.example.framework.exception.ExceptionConfig.class,
                }),
        })
@EnableAsync
@EnableCaching
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableScheduling
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(Main.class, args);
        MyAppInitializer initializer = appContext.getBean(MyAppInitializer.class);
        initializer.init(appContext);
    }
}

With normal execution the beans defined in ExceptionConfig are not initialized and I am able to write my own CustomExceptionConfig class
While running tests the ExceptionConfig is not excluded so the tests have different result than normal execution.
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Main.class, webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
public class ApiTest {
    .
    .
    .
}

I tried creating a separate test configuration like:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"org.example"},
        excludeFilters = {
                @ComponentScan.Filter(type = FilterType.ASSIGNABLE_TYPE, classes = {
                        org.example.framework.exception.ExceptionConfig.class,
                }),
        })
public class TestConfiguration {

}

And changing the ApiTest class:
@SpringBootTest(classes = {Main.class, TestConfiguration.class} , webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
Still the behaviour is same.
Defining a TypeExcludeFilter and using that in configuration class did not help either.
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class TestExcludeFilter extends TypeExcludeFilter {

    @Override
    public boolean match(MetadataReader metadataReader, MetadataReaderFactory metadataReaderFactory) throws IOException {
        return metadataReader.getClassMetadata().getClassName().equals("org.example.framework.exception.ExceptionConfig.class");
    }
}

